# Is it would had been or would have been?

Tags: tenses

Im not sure i understand the correct grammar for this sentence:

Yes, it would have been very awkward.

- or

Yes, it would had been very awkward.

it's referring to a time in the past.

What are the rules when using have or had in this situation?

Comment: _Would **have** been_. _Would_ is a modal auxiliary, which must be followed by an infinitive verb form. _Had_ is a past tense verb form; _have_ is an infinitive verb form. Q.E.D.

Comment: Welcome user3796133, I think this question can best be answered by searching on line for ***conditional past perfect***. You will find many explanations. Here is one http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/pastconditional.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"would have been"

The other one is totally, irrevocably, astoundingly wrong.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences

Et voila.

Comment: Thank you, i thought that it was fine as the other did sound quite wrong, though i had seen a few examples of people saying "would had", "would have" in that situation as both being okay.

Comment: Do you have a link to a text where someone says 'would had'?  Or to someone saying it is okay?